# handle errors while iterating over a mongo collection as stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have this simple method that go over mongo collection using akka streams, and for each element I call a method `enrichDataFromGoogleAndInsert` that calls google api to enrich the document data and insert it to new collection, 
  so `enrichDataFromGoogleAndInsert` is asynchronose.

```
   def processVendors()(implicit m: Materializer): Future[Done] = {
    val vendorsSource: Source[Vendor, Future[State]] =
      collection.find(json())
      .noCursorTimeout
      .cursor[Vendor]()
      .documentSource()
      .throttle(50, 1.second)

    vendorsSource
    .runForeach(vendor => 
      enrichDataFromGoogleAndInsert(vendor)
    )
  }
```

I run this method from my controller, and I want to know how could I accumulate the errors, and make sure the script dosent stop when `enrichDataFromGoogleAndInsert` is throwing some kind of error.

Comment: I suggest you first have a look at akka stream docs, as there is nothing specific to reactivemongo about that

Answer (score 0):

```
def processVendors()(implicit m: Materializer): Future[Done] = {
val vendorsSource: Source[Vendor, Future[State]] =
  collection.find(json())
    .noCursorTimeout
    .cursor[Vendor]()
    .documentSource()


vendorsSource
  .mapAsync(50)(vendor =>
    enrichDataFromGoogleAndInsert(vendor)
  )
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
}
```